# Using proxies with Unirest

Tags: python, proxy, unirest

I'm using the [Unirest library](http://unirest.io/python.html) for making async web requests with Python. I've read the documentation, but I wasn't able to find if I can use proxy with it. Maybe I'm just blind and there's a way to use it with Unirest?

Or is there some other way to specify proxy for Python? Proxies should be changed from script itself after making some requests, so this way should allow me to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Unirest, but, In all the scripts I wrote that requierd proxy support I used SocksiPy (http://socksipy.sourceforge.net) module. It support HTTP, SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 and it   s really easy to use. :)

Comment: I need to make async requests, I specified this in my question, so I can't use SocksiPy.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

[1] https://github.com/obriencj/python-promises